# Why is `<input />` dragging down the parent div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The `input` element seems to drag down the parent `div`.  Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

The html

```
  <div class="main">
    <div class="one">
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <input type="text" /> <!-- Without this input, the page looks fine -->
    </div>
    <div class="three">
    </div>
  </div>
```

The css

```
.main>div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 330px;
}

.one {
  width: 18%;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
}

.two {
  margin-left:10px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
}

.three {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border: 5px dashed #ddd;
}
```

Here is the effect: http://jsbin.com/gubozapove/edit?output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you have given: `display: inline-block;`. To work around this, give:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

**Preview**

[image]

**Reason:** Inline Block elements tend to align to the `baseline` by  default.

**Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/kitazeweqi/1/edit?output**

Comment: Wow. You are fast! Thank you. Now I know there is the `baseline`

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
vertical-align: text-top;
```

to your `.main>div`.

Comment: Boss, `text-top` seems risky. Can you try using `top`?

Comment: In which cases are you expecting it to fail?

Comment: Browser support? IE yuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it adding `float: left;` to `.one` and `.two`

Comment: I was about to explain. The OP wanted a reason and a fix. You totally gave a complex solution. I wanted your attention, that's the reason for downvote, but I removed it now.

Comment: @PraveenKumar understood